# how to export two gridview results one by one in mail thru c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to send two gridview output to mail using asp.net c#. Following code works fine and mail sent successfully. Whats the issue is, two gridview outputs are placed one by one without any line break. I need to give a line break after gridview1 gvPendingStatus and then to show gridview2 gvProductionTrend. How can be done. Plz help me out.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string MailSturcture;

    using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            gvPendingStatus.RenderControl(hw);
            gvProductionTrend.RenderControl(hw);
            System.IO.StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            sb.AppendFormat(sw.ToString());
            //  other Mail informations goes here... 
            }
        }
```

[image]

You can see both the gridviews are touched each other and I want the line break after Prakash Kumar row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
gvPendingStatus.RenderControl(hw);
hw.Write("<br>");
gvProductionTrend.RenderControl(hw);
```

or

```
gvPendingStatus.RenderControl(hw);
hw.WriteBreak();
gvProductionTrend.RenderControl(hw);
```